# how do i solve the image upload issue of laravel while hosting it on shared hosting?

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

[image][image]i am using hostinger to deploy my laravel project i uploaded all the files into the public_html folder and then did all the necessary changes needed for the application to work.The app seems to work pretty fine but when an user tries to upload a image the image gets stored in the storage/app/public/avatar folder and on public/storage/avatar folder as i have used symlink to link the two folders but yet the photos cannot be viewed by the users. this is how i recall my photo

div class="profile-avatar" style="width: 400px;height:500px; border-radius: 0%;background-image: url('@if(Auth::user()->avatar == "avatar.png") {{ url("/imgs/".Auth::user()->avatar) }} @else {{ url("/storage/avatar/".Auth::user()->avatar) }} @endif');"

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

As you have no ssh access to run some command in shell,
try this when uploading the image

**1. Store image here: public_path() . 'img/filename.jpg'***

***2. Save the 'img/filename.jpg' in database***

***3. Generate the image URL with url('img/filename.jpg')***

// Output  http://www.your-domain.com/img/filename.jpg

If you can manage ***shell access*** then try this:

Remove your current app/public/avatar directory, which is created inside of storage folder. 
Also remove your storage folder inside public !

After that via ssh cli, cd to your laravel project folder and create a symbolic link via following command

```
ln -sr storage public/storage
```

Hopefully it will solve your issue. I had same issue and mine got fixed via second method ( I had ssh access to my server ).

Comment: i am actually not using any type of shell

Comment: check your filesystem.php 

make sure you are using public_path() for the driver you are using to upload the photo. wait Im' editing my ans

Comment: i got access to ssh. now from the beginning please tell me where do i upload all my files on the host  as i deleted all the files in order to start from 0

Comment: in the above question i have provided how my laravel files look  and in the other image i have shown my host file manager looks like. please help me to know where to upload all the the files i.e in public_html file or the root file in order to execute the storage link command using ssh cli

Comment: go to your laravel project folder via ssh and execute the above commands I've given. 

I'm assuming you've created a symbolic link with your laravel_project/public folder with your public_html .

Comment: i didnt link anything yet. do i need to upload all my files in the public_html folder or i need to upload all the files in the root directory@fahim152

Comment: upload / clone ( if you have your project in gituhb ) your laravel project folder outside public_html. then make a symbolic link using ln -sr . like this. ln -sr laravel_project/public public_html . 

You see, whenever your domain url, your server will show up the file from public_html. And as per directory structure of laravel, only public folder is publicly accessible. 

So you are creating a symbolic link between your public_html and your laravel's public directory. So that whenever you hit the url of your server the public_html will access your laravel's public folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203871/discussion-between-jeffrin-jose-and-fahim152).